# Dudas de como verificar si algo existe en un diccionario

Tags: python, base-de-datos, diccionarios

yo de nuevo. Tengo una duda, por ejemplo tengo el siguiente diccionario

```
universidades = {
"universidad1": [601, 602, 603],
"universidad2": [101, 102, 103],
"universidad3": [550, 551, 552],
"universidad4": [220, 221, 222],
"universidad5": [770, 771, 772]
```

}

bueno, en mi codigo le pregunto al usuario si pertenece a la universidad 1, 2, 3 etc. Luego de que me indique su código le pregunto con que numero de carné se identifica.

Lo que yo quiero hacer es que el usuario meta su carnet de identificación y luego de eso el programa revise para decir si ese carnet realmente pertenece a una clave del diccionario o no, si está pues que lo agregue a una lista vacia pero eso ya es otro tema.

Alguna recomendacion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes hacer uso de la expresión [in](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-operations) y [not in](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-operations).

- Código:

```
data = {
        'a' : 1,
        'b' : 2,
        'c' : 3
}

# Verificamos si existe la key a en el diccionario data:
if 'a' in data:
        print("Existe key.")

# Verificamos si no existe la key d en el diccionario data:
if 'd' not in data:
        print("No existe key.")
```

Resultado:

```
Existe key.
No existe key.
```

Comment: También podías haber puesto el ```else``` para saber si no existe, pero creo que lo que das a entender es que también puedes validar si un elemento no existe, buen ejemplo

Comment: Sí, efectivamente. Gracias, @christian ;).